# Julia Querying from SQLite

Tags: julia

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=qUrtLJcehE0, I created a database called Movies. Within the database a table called movies was created and next an entry was also added,

```
using SQLite
db = SQLite.DB("Movies")
SQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies(movie_id REAL,movie_name TEXT, location TEXT)")
SQLite.execute(db,"INSERT INTO movies (movie_id,movie_name,location) VALUES(1,'Avengers','USA')")
```

However now when I try to Query the entry as follows,

```
SQLite.Query(db, "SELECT * from movies")
```

I get the this error, `Error: MethodError: no method matching SQLite.Query.(::SQLite.DB,::String)`.
Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load a table using SQLite package,

```
using SQLite
using DataFrames

# Make a connection
db = SQLite.DB("Movies")

# To find out all tables available in schema
tbls = SQLite.tables(db)

# To load a specific table (movies table from Movies.db)
q = "SELECT * FROM movies"
data = SQLite.DBInterface.execute(db,q)

# To get as a dataframe
df = DataFrames.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know SQL, but I think you want to use `SQLite.execute` again not `SQLite.Query`. `SQLite.Query` is a `struct` not a `function`, and it doesn't have any documentation. I don't think you are meant to call it externally. Further documentation is [here](https://juliadatabases.github.io/SQLite.jl/stable/#Types/Functions-1).

Method error means you are calling something with the wrong arguments. The `SQLite.Query` `struct` expects all of the following arguments:

```
struct Query
    stmt::Stmt
    status::Base.RefValue{Cint}
    names::Vector{Symbol}
    types::Vector{Type}
    lookup::Dict{Symbol, Int}
end
```

The `SQLite.execute` `function` expects arguments in one of these forms:

```
  SQLite.execute(db::SQLite.DB, sql, [params])
  SQLite.execute(stmt::SQLite.Stmt, [params])
```

By convention in Julia, functions are all lowercase and types are capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` function is defined in `DBInterface`. Might not be obvious, but the following works:

```
begin
    using SQLite;
    using DBInterface:execute;
    using TypedTables, DataFrames

    db = SQLite.DB()

    ( (id = i, name="Row number $i", v= rand() ) for i in 1:1000 ) |> 
    Table |> 
    SQLite.load!(db, "test")

    execute(db, "select * from test") |> Table

end
```